# Server Manager DirectAdmin Error: "There are no IPs on DirectAdmin server" - Boxbilling

Tags: php, billing, directadmin

I am not sure if this question is related to topics of Stackoverflow. I tried to post it on BoxBilling Forum but that does not seem to work. This is why I am asking here.

By the way, I am using BoxBilling for my web hosting business that uses Directadmin.

Everything is fine just a problem, it does not create any Reseller or user accounts. Whenever I try to activate an order from Boxbilling admin, I get the following error:

> Server Manager DirectAdmin Error: "There are no IPs on DirectAdmin
>   server"

I am using the following extension:
http://github.com/boxbilling/extensions/blob/master/bb-library/Server/Manager/Directadmin.php

I see the extension was last updated years ago!

Is there anyone who is using Directadmin with BoxBilling ? Or do you have a working extension for Boxbilling and Directadmin ? Or can you help me anyhow to get it working ?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue today when setting up my Boxbilling with DirectAdmin, its an extremely simple fix.

All you need to do is go to the Boxbilling admin page, then go to "Configuration" on the left side menu, then "Hosting plans and servers" under that, then under the servers list, go to yours and press the pencil icon, then select "Yes" for "Use secure connection", then save the server settings. It should work perfectly now!

(I know this is an old post, but I feel that someone else may google this issue in the future and I want the solution to be available!)